# Fit modified ERF to data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm using Matlab for data fitting for the first time and I cannot get it to fit my data properly. I have a few hundreds measured values which I normalise from `0-1` (see the linked image).

I then want to fit the data with a modified ERF namely: `0.5 + {0.5*[erf(x/(2*(t*d)^(1/2)))]}`. I want to extrapolate the value for `t` hence I even tried assigning a value to `d` (which is a know constant anyway) and substitute the initial `0.5` with a constant of unknown value to be found: `a + {0.5*[erf(x/(2*(t*6E-20)^(1/2)))]}`. I also tried using ERFC instead of ERF.

However, I always get a very steep fitted curve which does not match my data.
I know that, given a fixed `d`, I should get a value for `t` of around `3-7` from Matlab as I can fit the data well in Excel (in a qualitative way, ie: by eye) with the given function and a value for `t` of `3-7`.

I should probably mention that the fit in excel is done by finding the inflection point and using a slightly different equation to model the data above and below the inflection point. I also tried this method in Matlab but still could not make it work.

For some reason the fit from Matlab always returns the same value for `t` as the inserted start point and I always get the same steep curve no matter what method I use. My limits for `t` are `+/-inf`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Giuseppe

[Real data and fitted curve image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq9j8.jpg)

Comment: In the expression `0.5 + {0.5*[erf(x/(2*(td)^(1/2)))]}`, what is the variable and what are the parameters?

Comment: Thanks for your response. 'x' is the variable and 't' is the parameter ('d' that multiplies 't' is a constant which I know in advance)